# Properly rectifying stereo images for GPU (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have been using cv::StereoBM for a while, and am trying to switch to cuda::StereoBM (uses the GPU) but have run into a problem where they look completely different, even with the same settings and input images. I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142554/opencv-big-difference-between-stereosgbm-and-gpustereobm-gpu) post that the inputs for cuda need to be rectified differently than for cv::StereoBM. Specifically that the disparity must be in the range [0,256]. I have spent a while looking for other examples of how to rectify an image for cuda, but with no results. The output with cv::StereoBM looks decent, so my images are properly rectified for that. Is there a way to convert one rectifying type to the other?

If anyone is interested, here is the code I use to rectify for stereo (note: I am rectifying each image to get rid of and 'lens effects' before I run them through this program):

```
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    //#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        int numBoards = 20;
        int board_w = 9;
        int board_h = 14;

        Size board_sz = Size(board_w, board_h);
        int board_n = board_w*board_h;

        vector<vector<Point3f> > object_points;
        vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints1, imagePoints2;
        vector<Point2f> corners1, corners2;

        vector<Point3f> obj;
        for (int j=0; j<board_n; j++)
        {
            obj.push_back(Point3f(j/board_w, j%board_w, 0.0f));
        }

        Mat img1, img2, gray1, gray2, image1, image2;

    const char* right_cam_gst = "nvcamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=UYVY, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw, format=GRAY8, width=1280, height=720 ! appsink";

    const char* Left_cam_gst = "nvcamerasrc sensor-id=1 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=UYVY, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw, format=GRAY8, width=1280, height=720 ! appsink";


        VideoCapture cap1 = VideoCapture(right_cam_gst);
        VideoCapture cap2 = VideoCapture(Left_cam_gst);

        int success = 0, k = 0;
        bool found1 = false, found2 = false;

        Mat distCoeffs0;
        Mat intrinsic0;

        cv::FileStorage storage0("CamData0.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
        storage0["distCoeffs"] >> distCoeffs0;
        storage0["intrinsic"] >> intrinsic0;
        storage0.release();

        Mat distCoeffs1;
        Mat intrinsic1;

        cv::FileStorage storage1("CamData1.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
        storage1["distCoeffs"] >> distCoeffs1;
        storage1["intrinsic"] >> intrinsic1;
        storage1.release();


        while (success < numBoards)
        {
            cap1 >> image1;
            cap2 >> image2;
            //resize(img1, img1, Size(320, 280));
            //resize(img2, img2, Size(320, 280));
             undistort(image1, img1, intrinsic0, distCoeffs0);
             undistort(image2, img2, intrinsic1, distCoeffs1);

           //  cvtColor(img1, gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
           // cvtColor(img2, gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);




            found1 = findChessboardCorners(img1, board_sz, corners1, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
            found2 = findChessboardCorners(img2, board_sz, corners2, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

            if (found1)
            {
                cornerSubPix(img1, corners1, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
                drawChessboardCorners(img1, board_sz, corners1, found1);
            }

            if (found2)
            {
                cornerSubPix(img2, corners2, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
                drawChessboardCorners(img2, board_sz, corners2, found2);
            }

            imshow("image1", img1);
            imshow("image2", img2);

           k = waitKey(10);
        //    if (found1 && found2)
       //     {
      //          k = waitKey(0);
      //      }
            if (k == 27)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (k == ' ' && found1 !=0 && found2 != 0)
            {
                imagePoints1.push_back(corners1);
                imagePoints2.push_back(corners2);
                object_points.push_back(obj);
                printf ("Corners stored\n");
                success++;

                if (success >= numBoards)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        destroyAllWindows();
        printf("Starting Calibration\n");
        Mat CM1 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
        Mat CM2 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
        Mat D1, D2;
        Mat R, T, E, F;

        stereoCalibrate(object_points, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, 
                        CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, E, F,
                        CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH | CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST,
                        cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5));

        FileStorage fs1("mystereocalib.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
        fs1 << "CM1" << CM1;
        fs1 << "CM2" << CM2;
        fs1 << "D1" << D1;
        fs1 << "D2" << D2;
        fs1 << "R" << R;
        fs1 << "T" << T;
        fs1 << "E" << E;
        fs1 << "F" << F;

        printf("Done Calibration\n");

        printf("Starting Rectification\n");

        Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
        stereoRectify(CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);
        fs1 << "R1" << R1;
        fs1 << "R2" << R2;
        fs1 << "P1" << P1;
        fs1 << "P2" << P2;
        fs1 << "Q" << Q;
        fs1.release();
        printf("Done Rectification\n");

        printf("Applying Undistort\n");

        Mat map1x, map1y, map2x, map2y;
        Mat imgU1, imgU2, disp, disp8 , o1, o2;

        initUndistortRectifyMap(CM1, Mat(), R1, P1, img1.size(), CV_32FC1, map1x, map1y);
        initUndistortRectifyMap(CM2, Mat(), R2, P2, img2.size(), CV_32FC1, map2x, map2y);

        printf("Undistort complete\n");

        while(1)
        {    
            cap1 >> image1;
            cap2 >> image2;


  undistort(image1, img1, intrinsic0, distCoeffs0);
        undistort(image2, img2, intrinsic1, distCoeffs1);
        remap(img1, imgU1, map1x, map1y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
        remap(img2, imgU2, map2x, map2y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());

        imshow("image1", imgU1);
        imshow("image2", imgU2);

        k = waitKey(5);

        if(k==27)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cap1.release();
    cap2.release();

    return(0);
}
```

Images showing what the different methods output:

**StereoBM** (uses CPU)
[image]

**cuda::StereoBM** (Uses GPU)
[image]

Comment: Is there any way I can clarify this question? Or does nobody know what the answer is.

Comment: @ Zock77. Please provide your output images from opencv and cuda. Also provide your trial on the cuda code itself here. PErhaps some back_end errorcode or traceback as well? This helps to tackle the issue at hand.

Comment: This question clearly has nothing to do with CUDA programming, so I have removed the tag.

Comment: Isn't there something missing in your post? ("OP: here link to image [...]", "My [...] code example (attempt) goes here below [...]")

Comment: Oh I see, that comes from a later edit not done by yourself.

Comment: The code I'm running is not giving any errors. It is simply outputting a different result. If you check the link I referenced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142554/opencv-big-difference-between-stereosgbm-and-gpustereobm-gpu?noredirect=1&lq=1 You can see that he was having the exact same problem. I was hoping somebody could clarify his answer.

Comment: I get the feeling that nobody here knows the answer. I'll keep looking into it and make sure to post any breakthroughs if I find any :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! It looks like the big difference between CPU and GPU is the normalization of the input image. The rectification can remain the same. I found some example code from opencv, and hacked it down to bare bones to see what all the steps were. Surprisingly, there was no normalizing done before or after the disparity calculation. Here is the working code for GPU:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/cudastereo.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

          bool running;
          Mat left_src, right_src;
          Mat left, right;
          cuda::GpuMat d_left, d_right;

          int ndisp = 88;

          Ptr<cuda::StereoBM> bm;

          bm = cuda::createStereoBM(ndisp);



          // Load images
          left_src = imread("s1.png");
          right_src = imread("s2.png");

          cvtColor(left_src, left, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
          cvtColor(right_src, right, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


          d_left.upload(left);
          d_right.upload(right);

          imshow("left", left);
          imshow("right", right);



          // Prepare disparity map of specified type
          Mat disp(left.size(), CV_8U);
          cuda::GpuMat d_disp(left.size(), CV_8U);

          cout << endl;


          running = true;
          while (running)
          {

              bm->compute(d_left, d_right, d_disp);

              // Show results
              d_disp.download(disp);

              imshow("disparity", (Mat_<uchar>)disp);

              waitKey(1);
          }

    return 0;
}
```